# Do Guard Clauses Alone Require Unit Testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

## TLDR

Does this method require **Unit** Testing?  If your answer is Yes, please ensure you understand my thought process by reading the whole Question.

```
public void UpdateChildSomethings(int parentId, string newVal, int bulkSize) {
    var skip = 0;
    List<Child> children = null;
    while ((children = _.GetChildrenFromDB(parentId, skip, bulkSize)).Count > 0) {
        var alteredChildren = AlterChildren(children, newValue); // Note: AlterChildren is fully tested separately.
        _.BulkUpdateDB(alteredChildren);
        skip += bulkSize;
    }
}
```

## Foreword

First off, I am a heavy Unit Tester.  I do it often, and I do it well.  But given my experience, I have gained opinions and may need somebody to put my in my place, or provide me with documentation to support or oppose me.

Opening Disclaimer: If I have an obviously tested method (Like `Alter` and `AlterChildren` below), and they have Guard Clauses in them, I'm probably going to end up testing the Guard Clauses, if for nothing more than 100% coverage in those tests.  But apart from that...

## The Question

Let's begin my question with this method:

```
public void UpdateSomething(int id, string newVal) {
    var actualSomething = _.GetFromDB(id);
    var alteredSomething = Alter(actualSomething, newVal);
    _.UpdateDB(id, alteredSomething);
}
```

Does this method require Unit Testing?  For multiple reasons, I would personally say no, at least not at this time.  Especially if `Alter()` is abundantly tested.  The action of Getting from DB and Updating DB have no value to Unit Test, and would be mocked anyway.

Assuming you follow my mindset and agree that method shouldn't be tested, what about this method?

```
public void UpdateSomething(int id, string newVal) {
    var actualSomething = _.GetFromDB(id);
    if (actualSomething == null) return;
    var alteredSomething = Alter(actualSomething, newVal);
    _.UpdateDB(id, alteredSomething);
}
```

I added a "Guard Clause".  This is not business logic or calculation.  It is code which determines the flow of code and early return.  If I were to Unit Test this, I would essentially be testing the result of GetFromDB, and therefore be **Testing a Mock**.  As far as I am concerned, Testing a Mock is not a useful test.

## More Complex

But assuming you STILL follow my mindset and agree that Guard Clauses based on External Data is a waste to Unit Test, what about this method?

```
public void UpdateChildSomethings(int parentId, string newVal, int bulkSize) {
    var skip = 0;
    List<Child> children = null;
    while ((children = _.GetChildrenFromDB(parentId, skip, bulkSize)).Count > 0) {
        var alteredChildren = AlterChildren(children, newValue);
        _.BulkUpdateDB(alteredChildren);
        skip += bulkSize;
    }
}
```

For clarity, I'll refactor this to break down the `while` clause

```
/// Uses parentId to retrieve applicable children in chunks of bulkSize.
/// children are processed separately.
/// Passes processed children to the DB to be updated.
public void UpdateChildSomethings(int parentId, string newVal, int bulkSize) {
    var skip = 0;
    List<Child> children = null;
    while (true) {
        children = _.GetChildrenFromDB(parentId, skip, bulkSize);
        if (children.Count == 0) break;
        var alteredChildren = AlterChildren(children, newValue);
        _.BulkUpdateDB(alteredChildren);
        skip += bulkSize;
    }
}
```

At first glance, this looks complex enough to test, but what are you testing?  Once again assuming that `AlterChildren()` is abundantly tested, the only thing left to test is the result of GetChildrenFromDB(), which is mocked.  Once again **Testing a Mock**.  The only line here doing something is `skip += bulkSize`.  What would you be testing there, the `+=` operator?  I still don't see the point.

So, that is my most complex example, should it be Unit Tested?

Comment: Since testing if a method is called (not necessarily its return value) is of value, I would say those methods are candidates for testing. With the Moq framework I often Verify that mocked interfaces are at least called or not called or called a certain number of times as expected.

Comment: Trying not to influence answers... This is similar to my comment on "Testing the `+=` operator". I personally don't find value in that.  In my test/mock I create 500 records, in my test/mock I say "bulk 100", in my test/mock, I saw I want to make sure a mocked method was called 5 times.  These are all values my test created and checked, and not anything in the code.  Same thing with a method that only does: `return val1 + val2`.  Yes, that is a calculation, but the only thing you are testing is that your language's `+` operator works... I don't find value in testing that.

Comment: Add some documentation to the method that any other developer should know by reading the docs what this method is supposed to do without looking at the implementation. Write unit tests to proove the methods works as documented (which is exactly the expected behavior of the method). f.i. if *newVal* is null there will be no Alter and no Update (and no exception). This is not testing a mock

Comment: @SirRufo The only way to test this is by observing state changes to the mocked dependency where `UpdateDB` lives.  Knowing that, the only side-effects are either coming directly from the Mocks, from the standalone `+=` operator, or from implementation of `AlterChildren`. *newVal*'s null check, and many other things, are tested in `AlterChildren`'s tests.  This method does nothing but consume dependencies, and implement `AlterChildren`.  But I don't want to test implementation.  Can you provide a detailed answer with examples?

Comment: You have asserted in 2 places that you are testing a mock. That isn't true (at least in the code you posted). You are testing how your method responds to some data provider which happens to be a mock. Think of it the other way around. If GetChildrenFromDB were to return X, should you call AlterChildren and if so, what should those parameters look like. Whether those methods do the right thing is not your worry today. Single responsibility. So it is a useful test. Whether the test is needed is going to be circumstance specific. Some sort of trade-off between effort and consequences of any bug.

Answer (score 3):

The code in question here does not seem to contain any business logic. I think your point is: Should this be tested although it does not contain business logic and is fairly trivial?

There is nothing wrong with testing "mechanics" (as opposed to business logic). There is no reason you can only test business logic. `UpdateSomething` provides a service to other parts of the application. You have an interest in that service being performed correctly.

I do not quite see the difference between "guard clauses" and any other logic. It's behavior that is relevant to the functioning of the application.

You question whether logic based on external data is to be tested. I do not see this as a criterion either.

These things make it more likely that a test should be written: The code is easy to test; bugs have a high cost; quality is important for this piece of code; the test will not cause additional maintenance work; the test does not require much change to production code.

Act according to concrete criteria like that.

---

Update:

> Can you update your answer, or comment, about whether or not you'd test the simplest code example I gave under "Let's begin my question with this method", and why/not?

Well, I can't say that because I don't know how valuable this is to test to you. If you have other tests that implicitly exercise this then I'd tend not to test it I guess. I'm personally not keen on writing tests for trivial things but I guess that's a matter of personal experience. Really, I feel that the criteria you proposed in the question have no intrinsic bearing on the decision at all. The decision should be made according to the criteria I set forth. This means that I lack the knowledge to come to a decision.

In my career I have found time and time again that programming by rules does not work. Programming is like chess - it is infinitely complex. No set of rules can adequately make decisions for you. Rather, develop a mental toolbox of heuristics and patterns to guide you in the concrete case. In the end you must decide based on the concrete case as a whole, not based on a rigid rule. That's why I said "these things make tests more likely", not "you should test when...".

That's why rules such as "test getters and setters" or "do *not* test getters and setters" are simply false! Sometimes you test them, sometimes you don't.

Comment: I definitely feel "Act according to concrete criteria" such as "Testing is Easy, Bugs are Expensive."  I'm not 100% sure what "mechanics" means.  If that means testing Implementation (vs Behavior), I would disagree.  You're right that, as a rule, if a method is worth creating, it's worth ensuring it is being performed correctly.  Can you update your answer, or comment, about whether or not you'd test the simplest code example I gave under "Let's begin my question with this method", and why/not?

Comment: Well, I can't say that because I don't know how valuable this is to test to you. If you have other tests that implicitly exercise this then I'd tend not to test it I guess. I'm personally not keen on writing tests for trivial things but I guess that's a matter of personal experience. Really, I feel that the criteria you proposed in the question have no intrinsic bearing on the decision at all. The decision should be made according to the criteria I set forth. This means that I lack the knowledge to come to a decision.

Comment: In my career I have found time and time again that programming by rules does not work. Programming is like chess - it is infinitely complex. No set of rules can adequately make decisions for you. Rather, develop a mental toolbox of heuristics and patterns to guide you in the concrete case. In the end you must decide based on the concrete case as a whole, not based on a rigid rule. That's why I said "these things make tests more likely", not "you should test when...".

Comment: That's why rules such as "test getters and setters" or "do *not* test getters and setters" are simply false! Sometimes you test them, sometimes you don't.

Comment: Thanks for the time to specify.  I feel the same way, which is why I made sure my question was specifically about Guard Clauses "Alone", with no other considerations.  And also why I made sure to mention that, given other considerations, I would indeed test... including the guard clauses.  You said something similar, but more eloquently.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a combination of computations and interactions.  The value of unit-testing such code often appears questionable a) due to the effort for mocking and b) due to the resulting dependency of the unit-tests on implementation details.  One approach that often helps is to modify the code in a way that the computations and interactions are separated into different functions/methods.  Functions with computations are then tested using unit-testing with no or at least reduced need for mocking, and interaction dominated functions are tested with integration testing.

In your example, a possible separation between computations and interactions could look as shown below:

```
public int BulkUpdateChildren(int parentId, string newVal, int skip, int bulkSize) {
    List<Child> children = _.GetChildrenFromDB(parentId, skip, bulkSize);
    if (children.Count > 0) {
        var alteredChildren = AlterChildren(children, newValue);
        _.BulkUpdateDB(alteredChildren);
    }
    return children.Count;
}

public void UpdateChildSomethings(int parentId, string newVal, int bulkSize) {
    var skip = 0;
    var updated;
    do {
        updated = BulkUpdateChildren(parentId, newVal, skip, bulksize);
        skip += updated;
    } while (updated == bulksize);
}
```

The new method `BulkUpdateChildren` contains all the interactions with the dependencies - this would best be tested using integration testing.  What remains within `UpdateChildSomethings` is computation dominated, and testing it only requires to mock one single method within the SUT itself, namely the call to `BulkUpdateChildren`.  Unit-testing `UpdateChildSomethings` is therefore easier and can focus on the question whether in all possible cases the value of `skip` is updated properly and if the loop terminates as expected.

There is only very little logic left within `BulkUpdateChildren`, namely the check whether there were any children found, and the 'computation' of the return value.  Maybe the check for zero children is even unnecessary (unless for performance reasons), if the methods `AlterChildren` and `BulkUpdateDB` are able to deal with empty lists.  When leavin this check out, this code would consist almost only of interactions:

```
public int BulkUpdateChildren(int parentId, string newVal, int skip, int bulkSize) {
    List<Child> children = _.GetChildrenFromDB(parentId, skip, bulkSize);
    var alteredChildren = AlterChildren(children, newValue);
    _.BulkUpdateDB(alteredChildren);
    return children.Count;
}
```